# I train the model progressively due to lack of memory where keras supports progressive loading of dataset via fit_generator() function

Tags: jupyter-notebook

In image captioning model training, I am facing this error, anyone please help me with an solution with alternative code![enter image description here]
https://i.stack.imgur.com/xQYIO.jpg

Comment: You can use `ImageDataGenerator` it is present in `tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image.ImageDataGenerator` 

[Tensorflow Documentation Link](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/preprocessing/image/ImageDataGenerator)

Hope this solves the problem :-)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.